# Kafka lag with read_uncommitted isolation level

Tags: apache-kafka

Are uncommitted records counted in kafka lag if the consumer is configured to read only committed records?

I read the documentation but didn't find the answer there
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_lag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you poll and process an event without committing, then the lag will remain or increase, depending on new produced events. So, yes, lag includes uncommitted records.

If you're referring to *unfinished transactions*, then I recall there was a bug that always made lag be non-zero (at least one), as it was counting transaction markers, which are discarded automatically by the consumer.